# Difference in time complexity between python .index() and .find()

Tags: python, arrays, string

I was wondering what the difference in time complexity between `.find()` and `.index()` is in Python. When doing LeetCode I noticed, that the `.find()` method takes noticably longer then the `.index()` method. From my understanding both methods should run in `O(n)`.
The only difference I see is, that `.index()` throws a ValueError when the element you search is not present.

Does somebody know where this speed difference comes from? And also is there a document where you can find the time complexities for various Python methods?

Answer (score 2):

Both [`str.find`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/802b645e81a72399a7ef47ef000d468c775dcd3e/Objects/unicodeobject.c#L11982) and [`str.index`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/802b645e81a72399a7ef47ef000d468c775dcd3e/Objects/unicodeobject.c#L12059) are just thin wrappers around [`any_find_slice`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/802b645e81a72399a7ef47ef000d468c775dcd3e/Objects/unicodeobject.c#L9616), and their only meaningful difference is the addition of the following in `str.index`:

```
if (result < 0) {
    PyErr_SetString(PyExc_ValueError, "substring not found");
    return NULL;
}
```

Thus any perceived runtime differences *if true* (you haven't included a benchmark that shows your claims are true) must come from the exception handling.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I also thought that maybe the exception handling is the thing that adds runtime to the `.index()` call. However, the `.index()` call is actully faster (Sorry for not including this in the above question). This statement `''.join(sorted(T, key=lambda x: S.index(x) if x in S else 0))`needs 16 ms while `''.join(sorted(T, key=lambda x: S.find(x) if x in S else 0))` needs 32 ms (I know that the `x in S` is not neccesarry here, but I left it in for a fair comparison).